# Form does not submit values

Tags: python, django

I have a HTML form in Django and I'm not using Django form class.

Now I want to know how can I process this html form? (method is `POST`)

The form is genereted by `xsl` but the final generated form is like this:

```
<form method="POST" id="settingSubmit" action="/archive/agentUpdate/1">
    <input value="1" name="AgentID" datatype="Int">
    <input value=" agent 1" name="AgentName">
    <input value=" agent 1 Description" name="AgentDescription">
    <input value="submit" id="sendbutton" type="submit">
</form>
```

and the view:

```
def agentUpdate(request,id):
    agentName = request.POST['AgentName']

    return render_to_response('archive/base.html',{
        'agentName':agentName
    },
        RequestContext(request, ))
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('archive.views',

    url(r'^agentUpdate/(?P<id>\w+)/$',
        'agentUpdate',
        name='agent_Update'),
)
```

Error:

```
MultiValueDictKeyError at /archive/agentUpdate/2/

"Key 'AgentName' not found in <QueryDict: {}>"
```

Comment: Have you tried request.POST? Your question is very broad, although the answer may still be "use Django's forms" (but only for processing, if you do not need builtin HTML generation).

Comment: Are you sure this is the right code that's triggering the error? Is it the complete method? You don't have a `QueryDict` instance.

Comment: "I'm not using Django form class" Any particular reason why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix your form's HTML by adding `type="hidden"` to your form fields, otherwise they will not be submitted as part of your request.

You should also add `{% csrf_token %}` which required for [`CSRF` protection](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/). This is enabled by default on all `POST` requests.

```
<form method="POST" id="settingSubmit" action="/archive/agentUpdate/1">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input value="1" type="hidden" name="AgentID" datatype="Int">
    <input value=" agent 1" type="hidden" name="AgentName">
    <input value=" agent 1 Description" type="hidden" name="AgentDescription">
    <input value="submit" id="sendbutton" type="submit">
</form>
```

Finally, in your view:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def agentUpdate(request,id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        agentName = request.POST.get('AgentName')
        return render(request, 'archive/base.html', {'agentName':agentName})
```

Comment: I cannot add csrf_token; but the idea of hidden input helped.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding `MultiValueDictKeyError` you should do

```
agentName = request.POST.get('AgentName')
```

Also will be better to check if this is a `POST` request

```
if request.POST:
    agentName = request.POST.get('AgentName')
```

Then with this data you can do whatever you want - validate, save it to database, process in any other way.

Also instead of `render_to_response` you can use shortcut `render`

```
return render(request, 'archive/base.html', {'agentName': agentName})
```

Comment: The problem is request.POST is emty(__len__=0). Also when I try GET method is the same

Comment: How do you submit your form from html? I see no submit button?

Answer (score 0):

Add csrf token to your form

```
<form method="POST" id="settingSubmit" action="/archive/agentUpdate/1">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input value="1" type="hidden" name="AgentID" datatype="Int">
    <input value=" agent 1" type="hidden" name="AgentName">
    <input value=" agent 1 Description" type="hidden" name="AgentDescription">
    <input value="submit" id="sendbutton" type="submit">
</form>
```

In views.py add

from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

```
def agentUpdate(request,id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        agentName = request.POST.get('AgentName')
        variables = RequestContext(request, {'agentName':agentName})
        return render_to_response('archive/base.html', variables)
```

In urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('archive.views',

    (r'^agentUpdate/(\w*)\/?$','agentUpdate'),
)
```